# Where exactly is this view being loaded from?

Tags: laravel

```
@if (view()->exists('payment::' . $paymentMethod->name))

@endif
```

I came across this condition in a blade file and I can't figure out what the `payment::` section means. Where would I look for the actual blade file in my folder structure?

Comment: I think the view is from a package. Here is some documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/packages#views

Comment: @David Thanks. I appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating the package you can also provide the blade views along with your package. In the package service provider under boot method you can call `loadViewsFrom` method.

So the package you are using must have registered under the `payment` namespace.

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/pathtoview', 'payment');
```

Here is some of the links to the package that provided views out of the box

1. [rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer](https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer/blob/1a11c77d005670ac195a53f56bcda73f4d81ebb1/src/Rap2hpoutre/LaravelLogViewer/LaravelLogViewerServiceProvider.php#L26)  is registered under `laravel-log-viewer` namespace
2. [aschmelyun/larametrics](https://github.com/aschmelyun/larametrics/blob/6c1aa0d33abb4a778e552ba847d9dd2f634c29a3/src/LarametricsServiceProvider.php#L24) is registered under `larametrics` namespace